# Difference between async/await and async/fixture.whenStable in Angular

Tags: angular, unit-testing, asynchronous, async-await, karma-jasmine

I want to know the difference between these two methods for dealing with asynchronous calls in the Angular framework while testing:

- The first with the jasmine approach **async/await**
- The second with the Angular approach **async/fixture.whenStable**

Are they similar? If not, what is the difference, and when exactly should I use one rather than the other?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first approach of `async/await` is stock JavaScript where you want to run the function asynchronously and you can await for promises before carrying over to the next line.

```
it('it block in an async await way', async(done) => {
   await waitForThisFunctionThatReturnsAPromiseBeforeCarringForward();
   // do something, make assertions
   const x = await getXFromAPromise(); // wait for getXFromAPromise() function to return the promise
// and assign the results to x
   // do something, make assertions
   done(); // call done to ensure you have run through the whole it block and tell Jasmine you're done
});
```

The `fixture.whenStable` basically waits for all promises in the stack to be resolved before carrying forward with assertions.

```
it('demonstration of fixture.whenStable', async(done) => {
   // do some actions that will fire off promises
   await fixture.whenStable(); // wait until all promises in the call stack have been resolved
   // do some more assertions
   done(); // call done to tell Jasmine you're done with this test.
});
```

The done callback is optional but I use it to ensure for better engineering (make sure it traversed through the whole it block).

Edit ====================

To handle observables, I use two methods.

`async/await` with `take` and `toPromise` operator where you take the first emission and you convert it to a promise. Feel free to add other operators such as `filter` to ignore some emissions before the `take(1)`.

```
import { take } from 'rxjs/operators';
......
it('should do xyz', async done => {
  const x = await component.observable$.pipe(take(1)).toPromise();
  expect(x).toBe(....);
  done();
});
```

The other way is to `subscribe` with `done` callback

```
it('should do xyz', done => {
  component.observable$.subscribe(result => {
    expect(result).toBe(...);
    // call done here to ensure the test made it within the subscribe
    // and did the assertions and to let Jasmine know you're done with the tests
    done();
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for answering me! I want to know if those 2 approaches are available with Observables or only used for Promises?

Comment: Those approaches are only used for promises. I have edited my answer to show you how I deal with observables.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation! It helped me a lot

Comment: So should I use be using vanilla async/await in my tests or waitForAsync? Does it really matter?

Comment: @Red2678 it does not matter, it is a matter of preference.